# Use 'Could not' and 'Nor' in the same sentence

Tags: word-usage, neither-nor

I have a question about using '**Could not**' and '**nor**' in the same sentence.

Can I say or write:

> I **could not** find at A **nor** B

Is this the right grammar? Can I use both 'could not' and 'nor' in the one sentence?

Comment: I think you need to say either 'I could not find it at either A or B' OR 'I could find it at neither A nor B'.